# Getting correct data type of columns from view

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2012, sqldatatypes

I am trying to create a table from view. This view is from a join between multiple tables. But in the target table almost all columns have either Varchar(8000) or NVARCHAR(4000) which is not true for any of the columns. 
I tried to get the structure via

```
SELECT * INTO targetTable from SourceView
```

&

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE Table = 'SourceView'
```

both are giving me varchar and nvarchar datatype with very high range.

What is the correct way to get the source column data type?

[image]

Comment: Views normally correctly reflect the data types of the underlying columns, provided the columns are directly obtained from the base tables. Which suggests that this is a more complex view that is using expressions (casts , calling functions, case expressions, etc) in the `SELECT` clause. I'm also *slightly* fearful or those ordinal_position values.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, this is complex view and I think I got something from your comment. For almost all columns I have REPLACE(REPLACE(column,Char(13),'',Char(10),'') statement to remove special characters ( as we had faced special character issue using SSIS). I think this clause might be causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't analyse the inputs to functions. `REPLACE` is typed to return `varchar(8000)`/`nvarchar(4000)` (unless called with something of type `[n]varchar(max)`)

Comment: >>>both are giving me varchar and nvarchar datatype with very high range<<< But what is the problem with it? That is **maximum** possible size, it's not actual size that data will occupy (your type is VARchar, not fixed length char)

Comment: @damien_The_Unbeliever I got the correct data type after removing replace clause. Now this is embarrassing. Don't know if I have keep this question alive or delete it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if its the best solution performance wise , but you can just cast them in the select fields..

```
CREATE VIEW ...
SELECT CAST(DesiredColumn as varchar(50)) as DesiredColumn,
       ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have around 170 columns and I have to check base tables to identify their correct data type. This will be a hectic task and have chances of manual error. :(

Comment: Yea it probably will, and I normally won't suggest to do it, but I'm not sure if there's another way of determine to a view which types to select ..